# Can you please fix my table?

Tags: html, css, button

I have a table.

- I want all values and buttons should be in center horizontally and vertically.
- But the problem is: If I enter the button link as a value of any row then button and all other text values displaying broken and not vertically in middle.

See screenshot:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RAE6.png) 
Can you please fix this?

My code:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> -->
    <title>CSS3 Feature Table</title>

    <div id="main">
        <table class="features-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Standard</td>
                    <td>Links</td>
                    <td>Professional</td>
                    <td>Links</td>
                    <td>Business</td>
                    <td>Links</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td>Total</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td>Value1</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" style="background-color: blue" value="Features" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://www.facebook.com/', '_blank');">
                    </td>

                    <td>2000</td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" style="background-color: blue" value="Features" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://www.facebook.com/', '_blank');">
                    </td>
                    <td>3500</td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" style="background-color: blue" value="Features" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://www.facebook.com/', '_blank');">
                    </td>

                    <td>6000</td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>Value2</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" style="background-color: blue" value="Features" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://www.facebook.com/', '_blank');">
                    </td>

                    <td>1900</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" style="background-color: blue" value="Features" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://www.facebook.com/', '_blank');">
                    </td>
                    <td>3200</td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" style="background-color: blue" value="Features" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://www.facebook.com/', '_blank');">
                    </td>

                    <td>5000</td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>Value3</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>300</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>500</td>

                    <td>Value</td>

                    <td>900</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Value4</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>400</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>700</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>1000</td>
                </tr>




                <tr>
                    <td>Value5</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>500</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>1000</td>

                    <td>Value</td>

                    <td>3000</td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>Value6</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>200</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>300</td>

                    <td>Value</td>

                    <td>400</td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>Value7</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>100</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>300</td>

                    <td>Value</td>

                    <td>500</td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>Value8</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>200</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>500</td>

                    <td>Value</td>

                    <td>700</td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>value9</td>
                    <td>value</td>
                    <td>value</td>
                    <td>value</td>
                    <td>30</td>

                    <td>Value</td>

                    <td>50</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Value10</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>20</td>

                    <td>Value</td>

                    <td>30</td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>Value11</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>20</td>

                    <td>Value</td>

                    <td>30</td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>Value12</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>10</td>

                    <td>Value</td>

                    <td>15</td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>Value13</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>20</td>

                    <td>Value</td>

                    <td>40</td>

                </tr>



                <tr>
                    <td>Value14</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>15</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>30</td>

                    <td>Value</td>

                    <td>40</td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>Value15</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>30</td>

                    <td>Value</td>

                    <td>50</td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>Value16</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>300</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>700</td>

                    <td>Value</td>

                    <td>1000</td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>Value17</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>100</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>200</td>

                    <td>Value</td>

                    <td>300</td>
                </tr>



                <tr>
                    <td>Value18</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>100</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>200</td>

                    <td>Value</td>

                    <td>400</td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>Value19</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>100</td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                    <td>200</td>

                    <td>Value</td>

                    <td>300</td>
                </tr>


            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</head>

</html>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share your CSS as well please? Or create a code snippet using https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I have no css. So I gave you just the table.

Comment: Then the screenshot that you attached is that what you see using that code?

Comment: Oh, yes, if I enter the code into my wordpress editor then my site automatically shows the table as like as my screenshot.

Comment: Then you're using a css library. Once you have the page loaded, just open the console (F12), right click and copy everything and paste it in a jsfiddle (HTML & CSS).
Or just share the website's link here if you'd like.

Comment: It's my localhost. For the "Vlue1" cell I I inspected the element. And copied all appearing css from the right side. See all css displayed for "Value1" cell. http://pastebin.com/EbqjGrti

Answer (score 1):

you can add `vertical-align: middle;` in your css to make the table align its values to middle of the cell. Also add `text-align: center;` to make the text on the center of the cell.

here is my css for that:

`<style>
        .features-table{
          vertical-align: middle;
          text-align:center;
          width: 100%;
        }
      </style>`

The result is: 
[image]

Comment: here is my css for that:

`<style>
        .features-table{
          vertical-align: middle;
          text-align:center;
          width: 100%;
        }
      </style>`

Comment: HI, I think your code is correct. But why at my wordpress not working this. I think my site using any theme styles and our table css are not able to override the theme styles. If yes, how can I check and stop that?

Comment: you can try to inspect the html file by pressing F12? you can click the cell and inspect the css styles that affects it. or you can paste your wordpress url link here so I could check.

Comment: Okay, I inspected the element of ''Value1" and copied all css from the right side of inspect element window. Please see: http://pastebin.com/EbqjGrti

Comment: Hello, any solution please?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. From the code that you have pasted, there are several `text-align: left;`, ` vertical-align: top;` and `vertical-align: baseline;`. Just change those values to `text-align:center; vertical-align: middle` or override the code the style by doing: 

`.features-table tbody, .features-table thead, .features-table tr, .features-table th, .features-table td{
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}`